# Creating databases on an Android application

Tags: android, database

Wich software should I use to create databases to be used in an Android application? I never had any experience with it and have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just addthe db file to your assets.  Then copy it from assets to internal storage on startup if it doesn't exist yet.  Use a script on your PC to build the db file (sqlite runs on PCs as well).

Comment: db file is the database file generated by mysql, am I correct?

Comment: By SQLite's desktop libraries, not mysql.

Comment: I didn't want to install another program, but gonna do so, thanks